# How to segment out the region of interest in this mask

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Hi I got this mask as following, and I try to segment out the left panel.

[image]

I used the watershed method, so hope that it will return one single value for the left panel.

```
D = bwdist(~mask);
imshow(D,[],'InitialMagnification','fit');
```

[image]

```
Di = -D;
Di(~mask) = -Inf;
L = watershed(Di);
Lrgb = label2rgb(L,'jet');
imshow(Lrgb);
```

But instead I got this, can anyone help me with that or you have better suggestions in terms of the segmentation.

[image]

Comment: have you tried [eroding](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) the image? I think that should do the trick for you to get them to be separated enough so that `bwconncomp` will actually return 2 objects.

Comment: @ABC I did that in my answer. An opening is an erosion followed by a dilation.

Comment: Yes, but adding the component "line" just adds more unneeded processing, whereas an erosion directly on this image, is a less complicated approach that should get the desired answer. Additionally, its possible that dilation isn't needed depending on the application.
Either way, many ways to skin a cat :)

Comment: @ABC what would you erode the image with? Agree that there are many ways to do this. If you do have a better idea I'd like to see you post an answer. If not, no worries. All the best!

Comment: @rayryeng, I posted up an answer for you. You basically create your own custom structuring element instead of matlab's default ones (ei, 'disk', 'line', etc) and erode with that. It's quite simple. You can dilate back once the objects are separated with the same mask, and the pages will remain separated. I like this method a bit more since you have bit more control over the operation and you get a more intuitive feel of how to erode or dilate, but in this case it doesn't make that much of a difference- and your solution performs just as well :)

Comment: @ABC - I am fully aware of custom structuring elements! :).  When you said "custom", I thought you were talking about a more elaborate structuring element.  However, your solution created a square structuring element... that really isn't "custom" :P... you can create that by doing `se = strel('square', 6);`  You eroded then dilated, which is the same thing as an opening... by looking at your solution, it's basically the same as mine, but you used a square structuring element and you separated the erosion and dilation operations... but I digress. Thank you for posting your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing your answer, using `bwconncomp` is certainly a valid approach, but the problem here is that the left and right pages are connected if you look at the spine of the book.  Therefore, if you tried to do what you suggested, the entire book will be labelled as a single object, and that's probably not what you want.  As such, what I would suggest is to **separate** the pages first, then apply the labelling algorithm after you're done.

A simple morphological opening filter with a vertical line structuring element should do the trick.  To get good results, I used a line of length 100.  You also have some unnecessary border pixels and the image is actually RGB.  Therefore, I'm going to convert the image to binary then clear the border:

```
mask = imclearborder(im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUyDQ.png')));
```

I read in your image directly from StackOverflow.  Next, we'll apply the morphology I was talking about:

```
se = strel('line', 100, 90);
out = imopen(mask, se);
```

The second input of `strel` is the length of the line given that `'line'` is the flag you're using - this denotes a line structuring element, and the third input is the orientation of the line.  90 means 90 degrees, or a vertical line.

Next, we can use [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) instead of `bwconncomp`... not only because it's simpler to use, but it's faster.  `bwlabel` gives you a label matrix that labels each unique object in the image.  The objects are labelled in column-major order, so from top to bottom, left to right.

This means that the left page would be given label #1.... and so you can just do this to extract out the left page:

```
left_page = label == 1;
imshow(left_page);
```

We get this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As requested by @rayryeng here's a really easy way alternative to do this.

```
im = imread('xUyDQ.png');
im = im2bw(im); 
im = imerode(im, ones(6));
```

The result...

[image]

Dilating back...

```
im = imdilate(im, ones(6)); 
figure, imshow(im)
```

[image]

You can of course have a smaller erosion by decreasing the 6 to something smaller. What's happening is that I'm basically eroding with a custom structuring element which is a matrix of 6x6 of ones- what effectively happens is that on the borders 6 pixels are getting changed to zeros, so you get the desired separation between the pages that you are looking for.

Comment: The only difference between this answer and the one I wrote is that you provided a different structuring element.  `ones(6)` is a square structuring element that can be created by doing `se = strel('square', 6);`.  I wouldn't consider a square structuring element to be "custom". There really isn't much of a difference between the answer I wrote in comparison to what you have written here... only that you explicitly split up the erosion and dilation operations whereas I combined them with an opening, but I digress.  It's nice to see your thoughts in an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Ah, I should have looked at the .m file for imopen beforehand - you're right its just an erode+dilate! ... I thought there was a but more to it in the details of the function. I used it a while back but made the switch to using them separately as I didn't always want to have the same structuring element for both functions- and using 'square' and 'disk' seemed like too much magic, I like seeing the theory a bit more. Anyways, cool, always fun to geek out on comp vision :)

Comment: Ahhh yes fair enough. Actually your mindset is proper. Keep that up!.. And yes. Computer Vision is always fun to delve into :) now that I see where you're coming from, I've upvoted your answer. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figure it out that there is a matlab function bwconncomp that will label the components.

```
components = bwconncomp(mask);
c_ind = components.PixelIdxList;
```

Comment: Are you sure this separates between the two pages?  Does it not simply make both the left and right page as one label?  The pages are in fact connected when you look in the middle (the spine).  I'm actually writing something right now that not only separates the pages, but does label them  (via `bwconncomp` / `bwlabel`).

Comment: lol. thanks :)... just a lot of experience.  I deal with image processing problems daily.